# Sharepoint 2010 Webpart Column Display

Tags: web-part

How do I change what columns I see in my Webpart? I have several columns in my list and I have adjusted the order of the columns to appear as desired, However, I only see 6 of the 20 columns in my webpart and not the ones I want to be seen.

Comment: You can choose which columns are shown by editing the default view of a list or creating the new view.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

**A) For default view of list:**

1. Go to the List settings.
2. Scroll down to the "Views" section.
3. Select the view in which you want to change the columns.
4. Select/unselect the check boxes near column names or change the order of column from dropdown at right side of column name.
5. Click on Save.

**B) List web part added on Page:**

1. Go to the page where list web part is added.
2. Edit the Page from "PAGE" option in ribbon or settings icon from top right corner.
3. Select the list web part and click on "Edit Properties" from ribbon.
4. Click on "Edit Current View".
5. Select/unselect the check boxes near column names or change the order of column from dropdown at right side of column name.
6. Click on Save.